# android jni reading jobjectArray field fails

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to read the elements of a java class in native c code.

Java class is as below

```
static public class GraphViewData implements GraphViewDataInterface {
    public final double valueX;
    public final double valueY;
    public GraphViewData(double valueX, double valueY) {
        super();
        this.valueX = valueX;
        this.valueY = valueY;
    }
    @Override
    public double getX() {
        return valueX;
    }
    @Override
    public double getY() {
        return valueY;
    }
}
```

I am passing an array of this class to native function, and trying to read the `valueX` & `valueY` fields.

```
int Java_com_example_fftplot_PlotActivity_computeFFT(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz,jint function,jobjectArray data) {

int i;
jsize inLength = (*env)->GetArrayLength(env,data); //size of input object array
for(i = 0; i < inLength/8 ; i++){
    jobject inData = (*env)->GetObjectArrayElement(env,data,i);
    jclass inDataClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,data);
    jfieldID inXval = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,inDataClass,"valueX","D");
    jfieldID inYval = (*env)->GetFieldID(env,inDataClass,"valueY","D");
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "inXval =", "%l",inXval);
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, "inYval =", "%l",inYval);
}
}
```

But i get error , as below

```
01-25 17:29:15.780: W/dalvikvm(3958): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
01-25 17:29:15.780: W/dalvikvm(3958):              in Lcom/example/fftplot/PlotActivity;.computeFFT:(I[Lcom/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView$GraphViewData;)I (GetFieldID)
01-25 17:29:15.780: W/dalvikvm(3958): Pending exception is:
01-25 17:29:15.790: I/dalvikvm(3958): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no field with name='valueX' signature='D' in class [Lcom/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView$GraphViewData;
01-25 17:29:15.790: I/dalvikvm(3958):   at com.example.fftplot.PlotActivity.computeFFT(Native Method)
```

What i am doing wrong, also, what is the meaning of `JNI WARNING?`. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`no field with name='valueX' signature='D' in class [Lcom/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView$GraphViewData;`

Note the '[' in the class name.  You're looking for a field called `valueX` in the array class `GraphViewData[]` rather than the class `GraphViewData`.

Perhaps you meant to pass `inData` rather than `data` to `GetObjectClass`?

Comment: are you telling about `[` that comes in front of `[Lcom/jjoe64/graphview/GraphView$GraphViewData` ? Also i don't understand clearly what makes difference in looking for class and array class?[Because i thought array class, however is the class and are same!]

Comment: `Foo blah` is an instance of class `Foo`.  `Foo[] blahArray` is an array of instances of `Foo`.  In Java you could write `blah.valueX` or `blahArray[0].valueX`, but you couldn't write `blahArray.valueX`.  Internally, the VM creates a new class for "array of Foo" the first time you reference a `Foo[]`.

Comment: @nmxprime "Perhaps you meant" is a polite wording. Reread your code. The answer is indeed `jclass inDataClass = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env,inData);`

Comment: The `[` is part of the "class descriptor" of the array class, which is essentially the binary name with '/' instead of '.'.  A quick search on google didn't turn up a handy reference for class descriptors, but you can get the sense of it from the `Class#getName()` docs (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName%28%29).